# gdb for Rust in Ubuntu on Windows 10 is giving me Cannot insert Breakpoint 1 and Cannot access memory at address 0x8007b17 error

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, rust, windows-10, gdb

Trying to get gdb working for Rust and I'm not able to put in a simple breakpoint. Can't quite pin down what is going on.

I'm trying to debug the following main.rs file:

> ```
> 1 fn main() {
> 2     let a = 2;
> 3     let result = stack_only(a);
> 4     dbg!(result);
> 5 }
> 6
> 7 fn stack_only(b: i32) -> i32 {
> 8     let c = 3;
> 9     return b + c + stack_and_heap();
> 10 }
> 11
> 12 fn stack_and_heap() -> i32 {
> 13     let d = 5;
> 14     let e = Box::new(7);
> 15     return d + *e;
> 16 }
> ```

I run cargo build and it works fine outputting 17.  Great.  When I go into target/debug I'm able to run the file again which is rust_test, and that works fine as well.

Now I try to launch gdb by typing gdb rust_test and that opens fine.

I type break main.rs:2 to try and put a breakpoint on the second line right after main begins and that seems ok too.  When I type run, however, I get the error I mentioned in the title.

Below is what it looks like in full. Let me know if any other info from my side would be helpful.

I installed gdb on ubuntu from the following youtube link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjPNeu89tSM&t=236s

```
(gdb) list
1       fn main() {
2                       let a = 2;
3                       let result = stack_only(a);
4                       dbg!(result);
5       }
6
7       fn stack_only(b: i32) -> i32 {
8                       let c = 3;
9                       return b + c + stack_and_heap();
10      }
(gdb) break main.rs:2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7b17: file src/main.rs, line 2.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/tembolo381/Rust-Workspace/rust_test/target/debug/rust_test
warning: opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 3261.3261 failed: No such file or directory (2)
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8007b17
```

I tried to look up the message opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 3261.3261 failed and I see there is some hack here:https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8516

That didn't make any difference for me, however. Not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Can you use WSL 2? It doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Gave it a whirl but still getting the same problem. I used the below link on youtube to install WSL2. I tried both ubuntu and WSL to try it. Is there another distro you can recommend? Thanks for responding! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7Em1wjMiak&t=196s